# Can't get std::from_chars to auto detect base

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to use std::from_chars to convert std::string to integer specifically like this:

```
//selection_msg is read from a file and is a std::string
int selection_data;
auto result =  std::from_chars(selection_msg.data(),
               selection_msg.data() + selection_msg.size(),
               selection_data);
```

Now this works for a decimal selection_msg = "1234", selection_data = 1234 and the result ec=0.
But if selection_msg = "0xABC", selection_data = 0 the result ec=0 but importantly the ptr="xABC" indicating the x isn't part of a recognised pattern.

Note: IF I add the base:

```
auto result =  std::from_chars(selection_msg.data(),
               selection_msg.data() + selection_msg.size(),
               selection_data,
               16);
```

selection_msg = "ABC" parses just fine, but obviously I can't decode a parse a decimal.

The spec https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars seems to suggest "0x" should be a valid pattern am reading it wrong?

I was hoping to use the auto base detection to make the file input a bit more flexible.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. all tested in VS2019.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about auto base detection on that page.

Comment: "*The spec https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars seems to suggest "0x" should be a valid pattern*" It says precisely the opposite: "Expects the pattern identical to the one used by std::strtol in the default ("C") locale and the given non-zero numeric base, ***except that*** ... "0x" or "0X" prefixes are not recognized for base 16 "

Comment: @NicolBolas ah, I read that as: if you are specifically using base 16 it wasn't recognised!

Cool your emphasis has clarified it for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is no auto base detection for `from_chars`. It's a very low-level interface designed for performance, not flexibility.

If you want auto-detection, use `stoi` and friends.